# Fetching cookie

Tags: java, cookies, vert.x

I have a site **www.mysite.com**. This site is called from another site www.aaa.com where I stamp the cookie (say x = 1) from the server.

Now when my site is called from new site **www.new.com**, will I be able to fetch the cookie (x=1) that I had stamped from my server when my server was called from **www.aaa.com** ?

NOTE: All the above processes take place in the same browser.

I am trying to do access the cookie but not been able to do so. I am using vertx as the server.

Small snippet to fetch the cookies in the server:

```
public Set getAllCookiesName(RoutingContext context) {
    Set<Cookie> cookies = context.cookies();
    Set<String> cookieNames = new HashSet<String>();
    for (Cookie cookie: cookies) {
        cookieNames.add(cookie.getName());
    }
    return cookieNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not shared across different domains, however they can be shared between domains and their subdomains. For e.g.if your mysite is subdomain of another site www.aaa.com (mysite.aaa.com) then cookies could be shared. However it would depend on what path you set your cookie into.